# How are the creases/folds in this mesh for a sofa achieved?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, topology

I'm trying to create a model of a particular sofa and am using a preview image of an existing 3D model as a reference, but I'm stuck on how they achieved the small creases on the surface that are highlighted in red, and the corresponding very tidy mesh. I know that no sculpting (at least not in ZBrush or other software) was involved as the model was made entirely in 3DS Max and I don't believe it has any sculpting capabilities, but I'm otherwise a bit lost about how they achieved this. Any advice would be great! Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to achieve this effect with SCULPTING in Blender, a method that would definitely assist you is going to Sculpting >> Tools >> Crease  or using Blender's new Cloth Brushes.

Doing this without sculpting is also probably achievable, you will have to manually tweak the mesh to either pull or push vertices/faces to match the reference.
You also have the option to apply a normal map that has creases but personally I would find that a bit more tidious to do in Blender and would probably still require you to sculpt and bake the map yourself.